# I am going to or I will be going to

Tags: future-tense

Which sentence is the correct one, or are they both correct?

1. I am going to the post office in 2 hours. Shall I post the letter for you?
   or
2. I will be going to the post office in 2 hours. Shall I post the letter for you?